# How define triangle with SqlGeometry in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, geospatial, sqlgeometry

In SQL Server 2012 a polygon is consists of an exterior ring with zero or some interior rings. So every simple polygon (rectangle, square and ...) must have an exterior ring and

**From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895267.aspx):**

> The following criteria are needed for a ring to be acceptable.
>
> - The LineString instance must be accepted.
> - The LineString instance must have at least **four** points.
> - The starting and ending points of the LineString instance must be the same.

So what if I want to declare a **triangle** with three points in SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Microsoft:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895267.aspx

```
DECLARE @g geometry;
SET @g = geometry::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((100 100, 200 200, 300 100, 100 100))', 0);
SELECT @g.ToString();
```

It has 3 points and then returns to its starting point (100,100).  You can see the area returns 10000, which is consistent with a triangle of base 200 and height 100:

```
SELECT @g.STArea();
```

Comment: So why they are saying `The LineString instance must have at least four points.`?

Comment: Because the polygon has to close